# combining two ideas with 'whereas'

Tags: legalese, clauses, existentials

I want to tell two ideas within a sentence. for that I am trying to use whereas;

Not sure, how the construction would be.

> 1. The recognition of canopies is well advanced in the forest regions,
>      whereas the extraction of the canopies located in the urban areas is
>      still a challenge.
> 2. The recognition of canopies is well advanced in the forest regions,
>      whereas the extraction of the canopies located in the urban areas, **it**
>      is still a challenge.

I am not sure I can write this is both ways as above. thanks

Comment: @snailboat: thanks. other than that, can i write the sentence in both way?

Comment: @snailboat: i'v corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Daniel's answer, more probably correct is "whereas the extraction of canopies located in urban areas is still a challenge."  Your sentence assumes that both the canopies and the urban areas that they are in have been previously mentioned, and my feeling is that you haven't.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is the correct way to formulate the sentence. The first part of the second clause is the subject of that clause, so there is no need to have a pronoun standing in for the subject.